# Confusion regarding the fixed point $p(x) =x$

Tags: probability

Consider an empty urn. Now at each time, we are adding one ball to it, Either red or black, the probability of a red ball being added depends on $x$ ($x$ denotes the current fraction of red balls in the urn) i.e. $p(x)$. I see in a book solving $p(x) = x$. Why is this fixed point important to compute? what does it signify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly.. The fixed point is often seen as being the "steady state" distribution for the system (given certain assumptions). Meaning that if you can solve that equation (exactly or numerically), you would have the expected number of balls after you iterate this process many, many times.

Answer (score 3):

$p(x)=x$ means that the *expected proportion* of red balls *added* to the urn will be exactly the proportion of red balls *already in* the urn.   Thus the proportion of red balls in the urn is unlikely to change dramatically after this point.

That is: it is an equilibrium point.